# I am new to jQuery and JSON. I need help in formatting the string so that I can iterate over it

Tags: javascript, json

This is the controller.

```js
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
@RequestMapping("/getDropDownAjax")
public void forA(HttpServletRequest req,HttpServletResponse resp){
 
 System.out.println("through ajax");
 
 String aString=service.getA();
 
 
 try {
  resp.getWriter().write(aString);
 } catch (IOException e) {
  // TODO Auto-generated catch block
  e.printStackTrace();
 }
 
}
```

This controller requests the service layer and it returns:
    [pg,ug]

This is the ajax part

```js
function callAjax(){
$.ajax({
 type:"GET",
 url:"getDropDownAjax.htm",
 
 success:function(data)
   {
   alert("success");
   console.log(data); 

   },
   
 error:function(){
   alert("failed");
 },
});

}
```

Now, I need to have pg seperately and ug seperately, so that I can add it to a select box. Thank you

Comment: what does console.log(data) give you?

Comment: data[0]: pg, data[1]:ug

Comment: it gives [pg, ug]   
with the brackets

Comment: in that case, your data is coming as string....parse it to json first. `jQuery.parseJSON(data)`

Comment: whenever I use jQuery.parseJSON(data)  , it gives the following error: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token p

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function callAjax(){
$.ajax({
    type:"GET",
    dataType:"json", //will tell jquery to parse result as json
    url:"getDropDownAjax.htm",

    success:function(data)
            {
            alert("success");
            console.log(data);

            //iterate over each elem of the array response
            for (var i in data) {
               alert(data[i]);
            }   

            },

    error:function(){
            alert("failed");
    },
});

}
```

look over the comments

Comment: in alert it shows all the characters one by one:  [  p  g  , u  g  ]
total 7 alerts for 7 characters

Answer (score 0):

Use `jQuery.parseJSON( json string )` function on ajax success

```
 function callAjax(){
    $.ajax({
        type:"GET",
        url:"getDropDownAjax.htm",

        success:function(data)
                {
                var data = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
                alert("success");
                console.log(data);  

                },

        error:function(){
                alert("failed");
        },
    });

    }
```

Comment: it gives the following error: 
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token p

Answer (score 0):

This solved it. Thanks all

```js
success:function(data)
             {
             alert("success");
             console.log(data);
             
             var s=data.slice(1, -1);
             alert(s);
             var dept=s.split(",");
             for(var l in dept)
             {
              alert (dept[l]);
             }
             
             
             },
```